# Unexpected output of Reduce() function in r

Tags: r

In `Tau[[i]][[j]]` I would like to divided the first vector of  `w` by the sum of all its vectors.  I have list of two vectors. Each vector contains 10 elements.  However, I saw the first result returns `1 1` which is wrong. That is, `Tau[[1]][[1]]` returns `1 1`. This is wrong. My code works very good except the code for `Tau`.

Here is my code:

```
vecW <- list(c(0.5, 0.6, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.6, 0.3),

             c(0.5, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.4, 0.7))

    mat1 <- c(0, 0.5, 0.6, 0.5, 0.5,
          0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5,
          0, 0, 0, 0.4, 0.6,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0.3,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
mat1 <- matrix(mat1, 5, 5)

mat2 <- c(0, 0.5, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5,
          0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5,
          0, 0, 0, 0.4, 0.4,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0.7,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
mat2 <- matrix(mat2, 5, 5)
mat <- list(mat1, mat2)


set.seed(47)
    a <-lower_tris <- list_of_pairs <-  vector("list",2)
    w <- Tau <- vector("list",2)
    for( i in seq_along(a)){
        for(j in 1:10){



a[[i]] <- array(rnorm(5 * 5 * 2), c(5, 5, 2))
    for(k in seq(dim(a[[1]])[3])) a[[i]][,,k][upper.tri(a[[i]][,,k], diag = TRUE)] <- 0


lower_tris[[i]] <- apply(a[[i]], 3, function(x){x[lower.tri(x)]}) 

list_of_pairs[[i]] <- split(lower_tris[[i]], seq(nrow(lower_tris[[i]])))

vecW <- lapply(mat, function(x){x[lower.tri(x)]})

w[[i]][[j]] <- vecW[[i]][[j]] * list_of_pairs[[i]][[j]]

Tau[[i]][[j]] <- w[[i]][[j]] / Reduce('+',w[[i]])
    }
}
```

Where is my problem? and how can I fixed it?

Comment: When emails are lengthy people scroll down and ignore i.e. `TL;DR` , `too long didn't read`. Your example is similar to a long email. Explaining in words what you are trying to accomplish could help.

Comment: I just would like in `Tau[[I]][[j]]` to get the correct output not only `1 1`. My code will run in second. So, my problem is only in `Tau`

Comment: Do you need the sum of each vector in `w[[i]]` or the total sum of the vectors contained in it?

Comment: I am just wondering whether you need `Tau[[i]][[j]] <- w[[i]][[j]] / Reduce('+',w[[i]][[j]])`

Comment: @akrun I just so your comment. Will,  `Reduce('+',w[[i]][[j]])` sum all the element of `w[[i]]`.

Comment: @Alice It was based on your comment that you are getting 1s for the first element.  With `w[[i]][[j]]`, it is not the case

Comment: @akrun, Ok, I will see if it works as I want. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Alice You can use a print statement `print(Reduce('+', w[[i]][[j]]))` and `print(Reduce('+', w[[i]]))`.  The first one gives a single value per iteration i.e. `[1] -0.4485087
[1] 1.510464` but the `w[[i]]`, sum gives two values `[1]  0.3555713 -0.8040800
[1]  1.5485175 -0.4865619`

Comment: @akrun oh. I see. I will try it. if your idea is what I want, then I will let you know to write it as answer.

Comment: @akrun Thank you for your comments. The idea is I would like to divide each vector of each element of the list by the sum of all the vectors of that element. e.g, my list contains two element each with 10 vectors. Then, I would like to divide the first vector of my first element by the sum of all vectors of that element.

Comment: @akrun if I tried it manually then it works just fine.

Comment: Could you show the manual way?  I get only two values for `Reduce` i.e. `Reduce('+', w[[1]])#
[1] 0.691452334 0.007313218`

Comment: @akrun sorry, my problem is only with my first vector. I did it like this:  `w[[1]][[1]] / Reduce('+',w[[1]])`

Comment: @akrun so my idea is like this one `w[[1]][[1]] / Reduce('+',w[[1]])` . However, I have to do it for all element.

Comment: So, in your loop, [[1]][[1]] is the `[[i]][[j]]` right?  I don't find any problem in that loop.  For me `w[[1]][[1]]
[1] 0.8378124 0.4192215
> w[[1]][[2]]
[1] 1.192946 0.317518
> w[[1]][[3]]
[1] -0.4935292 -0.5441543` and ` Reduce('+', w[[1]])
[1] 0.691452334 0.007313218
> Reduce('+', w[[2]])
[1] 2.760666 1.982956`

Comment: @akrun, if you do it one by one it works fine. However, the problem  in loop.

Comment: @akrun, I am really confused. it sometimes works just fine and sometime not. Also, when I use the suggested idea in the answer it works. `sum(unlist(w[[i]]))`

Comment: @akrun Thank you so much for your great and kind help.

Comment: There is a difference i.e. `sum` of `unlist` gives a single value, while `Reduce` is getting the sum of all corresponding elements.  Here, you have two elements for each list element, so you get two values i.e. ` `sum(unlist(w[[1]]))
[1] 0.6987656
> Reduce(`+`, w[[1]])
[1] 0.691452334 0.007313218
> Reduce(`+`, w[[2]])
[1] 2.760666 1.982956
> sum(unlist(w[[2]]))
[1] 4.743623`  and `sum(Reduce(`+`, w[[2]]))
#[1] 4.743623` gets the same value

Comment: @akrun yes, I need a single value.

Comment: In that case `sum(unlist(w[[i]]))` will be faster than `sum(Reduce('+', w[[i]]))`

Comment: @akrun you have great information and I learned a lot from you.

Comment: @Alice No problem, glad to help you.  Also, thank you for your questions.

Comment: @akrun if I want to find the mean for each `Tau[[i]][[j]]` is it good to use `mean(Tau[[i]][[j]])`

Comment: @Alic Looks like you can do it `mean(Tau[[1]][[1]])#
[1] 0.5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the sum of all vectors (to get a scalar) I think is sufficient doing `sum(unlist(w[[i]]))` instead of `Reduce('+', w[[i]])`.

Comment: I would like `Reduce('+',w[[I]])` to sum all the values in the first element of the list.

Comment: it works fine only for the first vector of the list.